# NVMe M.2 drive trouble: Won't boot, can't format or reinstall, data accessible

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, nvme

My laptop ran out of battery and shut down at 0%. When I charged it back up, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS couldn't boot and dropped to [initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs) after grub. Nothing I try will stick to get it working. At this point I am just trying to get the hard drive back to a state where I can reinstall Ubuntu.

System information: Ubuntu 18.04.3 fully updated as of a couple days ago. The hard drive is an NVMe M.2 2280 HP EX900 in a Dell XPS 13 9365. It was set up utilizing GPT and EFI, not legacy modes.

`exit` from initramfs says to run fsck because there is data in the journal. Running fsck (and fsck.ext4) from initramfs results in it saying it was unable to set the superblock flags and is still dirty. Research shows this result is because fsck could not actually write to the drive.

Booting from the Ubuntu installer live image, if I do anything with gparted, it shows as successful, but nothing changes. Delete partitions, make new ones, reformatting, convert to GPT: no errors pop up, but the hard drive partition scheme shows up the same as before I tried anything.

I can't reinstall Ubuntu. The installer hangs once it tries to repartition--and doesn't work if I choose to install in the existing partition.

The program boot-repair doesn't change anything, even messing with advanced settings.

If I install nvme-cli tools and try to format the drive or delete the namespace, it comes back with an error. The error varies, but it's unsuccessful every time. nvme id and log commands all show no problems with the drive/partitions.

I'd write this off as something wrong with the drive, except from Disks I can mount the partitions and access all of the data fine. I backed up my data from those partitions, so everything can be scrapped. I am just trying to get the hard drive to be accessible again so that the computer is usable. I don't care if I get the existing system working or reinstall Ubuntu.

Thank you, and I appreciate any and all assistance. I'm at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: Appreciate your diligence and thoroughness. I've had multiple instances where gnome-disks http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disks.1.html can solve problems gparted cannot. Please try deleting the partition(s) with Disks, then exit, reopen Disks, and create an ext4 partition; exit and recheck. After, click on [edit] and add results to your question with [edit]; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].